# Unit testing user interaction in an angular2 component

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine

I've recently started learning angular2, and I thought I'd try and write a combobox component similar to select2. Here's a simplified version of the component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'combobox',
    template: `
        <div class="combobox-wrapper">
            <input type="text"></input>
            <button class="toggle-button"></button>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="isDropdownOpen" class="dropdown">
            <div *ngFor="let option of options; let index = index;"
                class="option"
                [class.focused]="focusedIndex==index">
                {{option.label}}
            </div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class ComboboxComponent {
    @Input() options: any[] = [];
    isDropdownOpen: boolean = false;
    focusedIndex: number = 0;
}
```

I'm struggling when it comes to writing unit tests involving user interaction. For example, I want the user to be able to navigate the list of options by using the up and down keys on the keyboard. The way I see it, I have two options.

**Option 1:**

```
describe('when the dropdown is open and the user presses the "UP" key', () => {
    it('should focus the first available preceeding option', () => {
        const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.toggle-button'));
        const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));

        button.triggerEventHandler('mousedown', {});
        input.triggerEventHandler('keydown', { key: 'ArrowDown' });
        input.triggerEventHandler('keydown', { key: 'ArrowDown' });
        input.triggerEventHandler('keydown', { key: 'ArrowUp' });
        fixture.detectChanges();

        const options = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.option'));
        expect(options[1].nativeElement.className).toContain('focused');
    });
});
```

**Option 2:**

```
describe('when the dropdown is open and the user presses the "UP" key', () => {
    it('should focus the first available preceeding option', () => {
        const combobox = fixture.componentInstance;
        combobox.isDropdownOpen = true;
        combobox.focusedIndex = 2;

        input.triggerEventHandler('keydown', { key: 'ArrowUp' });
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(combobox.focusedIndex).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

Neither option feels right. In the first case I'm making assumptions about behaviour that is not part of the test itself - namely that clicking the "toggle" button will open the dropdown, and that pressing the "ArrowDown" key will focus the next option on the list.

In the second case I'm accessing properties that are not part of the component's public interface (@Inputs and @Outputs), and the test itself requires detailed knowledge about the actual implementation.

How should I approach this?

Comment: where is ngModel defined in your `<input type="text"/>` without which how will you get the data in your component?

Comment: If you are testing that `ArrowUp` works, I don't see any issue with method 1, but I would also ensure you have a test for `ArrowDown`, to ensure that the test isn't passing as a false positive. You're right, it does feel a little hacky, but unit testing in the browser can sometimes feel weird.

Comment: I sort of forgot about this thread, sorry for the late reply. As of right now I agree with @Adam, and I'm writing tests as shown in Option 1, which I think is the lesser of two evils.